# bootstrap-select data-style does not work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style my selectbox (http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) with

```
data-style="btn-info"
```

but it has no effect. This is the whole code:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-width="25%" data-style="btn-info">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
   <option>6</option>
   <option>7</option>
   <option>8</option>
   <option>9</option>
   <option>10</option>
</select>
```

The data-width also dows not work. Has anyone an idea? Here is my testsite: http://testshop.mein-sporttagebuch.de/produkte/details/0001. You will find the relevant selectbox on the right side.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off the top of my head... data-style="btn btn-info"

Comment: @TroyCarlson: Sorry, but it is not the solution. Think you mean just bootstrap, but I use additionally bootstrap-select that uses the style of bootstrap.

Comment: It looks like your `data-width=25%` is being overridden by `<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select" style="width: 150px;">`. Are you adding this code or is it generated? If I change the `150px` to `25%` it looks fine.

Comment: @MichaelFreake: Yes, I also noticed that the autogenerated code <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select" style="width: 150px;"> overrides my 25%. But it is autogenerated! In my opinion it should take my 25% and not the standard value...

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Bootstrap select?

Comment: @Skelly: Yes, downloaded it 2 weeks ago from the distributors page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'http://testshop.mein-sporttagebuch.de/application/javascript/main.js' is setting options when the select is instantiated which will override any data attributes set on the elements..

```
/* Select Box */
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-primary'
    ,size: "auto"
    ,width: "150px"
});
```

change to..

```
/* Select Box */
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({

});
```

Comment: I would like to upvote your answer 100 times. Thank you so much finding out this issue. Shame on me overriding the css-class.